# Converting an if/else statement into a code that allows for more than one choice

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix, switch-statement, octave

So I am trying to convert the following code in way that I would be able to use more than just one of the choices. (What happens inside of the cases does not matter, I would simply like to figure out how I could use more than one cases at once)

```
%% Creating a matrix Rot representing the rotational transformation that is applied. 
theta = input('Input the value of angle: ');

% Choose the direction 
Dir = input('Input around which axis the rotation occurs (x, y or z): ', 's'); 

if Dir == 'x'  
    Rot = [1 0 0;0 cosd(theta) -sind(theta);0 sind(theta) cos(theta)];
    
elseif Dir == 'y'
    Rot = [cosd(theta) 0 sind(theta);0 1 0;0 -sind(theta) cos(theta)];
    
elseif Dir == 'z'
     Rot = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0;0 sind(theta) cos(theta);0 0 1];
else 
    disp('Not an axis.')
    Rot = input('Input Rotational Transformation Matrix: ')

end
```

I tried using switches/cases or conditions, but I wasn't able to obtain a different results.

The end objective of this code is to be able to choose which direction a stress tensor will be rotated. My code works for simple cases, but i would like it to be able to calculate with a 30degree rotation in x and a 45 in y for example without rerunning the code.

Comment: If you want to build arbitrary rotations you will need to compute the 3 rotation matrices and compose them appropriately or alternatively build the whole general rotation matrix in one go. See Euler Angles in the wikipedia.  Make a function that takes angles for the rotation along the 3 axis, inside compute the rotation matrices, compose them and return the matrix.

No need for switches and ifs.

Comment: If understand correctly do something as such:


`% Rotational Transformations for part B
% Rotation about X
Rotx = [1 0 0;0 cosd(theta) sind(theta); 0 -sind(theta) cosd(theta)];
% Rotation about Y
Roty = [cosd(beta) 0 sind(beta) ; 0 1 0 ;-sind(beta) 0 cosd(beta)];
% Rotation about Z
Rotz = [cosd(alpha) sind(alpha) 0; -sind(alpha) cosd(alpha) 0; 0 0 1];


% Perform transformation
T =  Rotx * Roty  * Rotz; 

% Calculate Resultant Matrix
R = T * S * T.'; `

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, the title doesn't seem to have anything to do with the rotation itself, but you seem to care more about rotating rather than making multiple choices. In any case, if you're using octave, have a look at the matgeom package (https://octave.sourceforge.io/matgeom/overview.html) -- search that page for the keyword 'rot' to spot all the rotation / transformation functions.   (there's also rotx, roty, and rotz in the octave base)

Comment: okay, my main question has nothing to do with rotations, so I understand the confusion, my goal is to build a code where I am able to choose between choices and applied them to my code. What I posted is what i have for now. That code allows me to ONLY choose one of the x, y or z options. However i would like to be able to choose for example x and y (What happens inside of the the cases doesn't really matter for this question )

Comment: @WisePotato15 ok this makes more sense, but it's still vague E.g., if you choose 'x and y', what is the final `Rot` output? Presumably you don't just want the 'y' step to overwrite the one created by the 'x' step. So the answer depends on what exactly you want to do for the 'both x and y' option. However, assuming you're happy to create separate scenarios for each possible combination of outcomes, the typical way this is done is to create 'flags'. E.g. the user chooses '101' corresponding to 'x and z but not y'. Then 101 in binary is 5 in decimal, so choose option No.5 in your list of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about code flow, the simplest replacement to a chain of `if/elseif/else` is to use a `switch` statement.

```
switch Dir
    % for a single axis rotation
    case 'x'
        % Code for a rotation about a single axes ('X')
    case 'y'
        % Code for a rotation about a single axes ('Y')
    case 'z'
        % Code for a rotation about a single axes ('Z')
    
    %% For complex rotation about more than one axes
    case 'xy'
        % Code for a rotation about 2 axes ('X' and 'Y')
    case 'xz'
        % Code for a rotation about 2 axes ('X' and 'Z')
    case 'yz'
        % Code for a rotation about 2 axes ('Y' and 'Z')

    case 'xyz'
        % Code for a rotation about 3 axes ('X', 'Y' and 'Z')

    otherwise
        % advise user to re-input "Dir"
end
```

Alternatively, you could also use a *flag* system like mentionned in @Tasos Papastylianou comment under your question. It is a bit more technical to implement but a perfectly good solution too.

---

Now this only take care about the code flow. The actual validity of the calculations in each case is up to you. For the rotation about more than one axis, remember that the order in which you apply the rotations is important: rotating around `X` first, then around `Y`, can yield a different result than rotating around `Y` first then `X`, even if the rotation angles for each axis were the same.